# Как снять ограничение на мин. свободного пространства или вырезать?

Tags: установка, ubuntu

Установка Ubuntu. Нужно установить Ubuntu 11.10 на флешку 4 Гига. Все решить могу, кроме этого.

Comment: Пожалуйста опишите подробности Вашего дела - не вполне понятно, что Вы хотите...

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/устройство
```